# How do I make my alarm type app tick in the background? (IOS 10.2)

Tags: ios, timer, background

I am making a Pomodoro app that basically counts down 25 minutes and short 5 or ten minute breaks in between. I am a beginner at coding in xcode and I don't know how to let my app run in the background and alert me when the 25 minutes are up. I got it working in the foreground but my goal is to be able to exit the app or lock my device and let the timer keep running.

Answer (score 0):

Your timer might work for while in background but real question is how will you manage when app is killed.

Here is how i have done(for managing when app is terminated).

1. Store you date (NSDate) in User Defaults when your app timer is started.
2. Fetch your above stored Date from user defaults.
3. Get Current date
4. Subtract your save date from current date, you will get How much time have passed until now.

This is how you will get how much time is already ticked and you will have to manage the remaining time.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the timer running you should follow Dev_Tandel answer. But if you want to get alarm while your app is killed or is in background, you can use **Local Notifications**.

You can follow the tutorial at http://useyourloaf.com/blog/local-notifications-with-ios-10/